# Show repeating records as a single record

Tags: sql-server

I combine 3 tables. But there are lines that repeat in single tablature. I want to show them as a single line.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(gelenhaberlerimage.HaberKodu) AS Expr1,
  gelenhaberaciklama.id,
  gelenhaberaciklama.HaberKodu,
  gelenhaberler.id AS Expr2,
  gelenhaberler.HaberKodu AS Expr3,
  gelenhaberler.Sehir,
  gelenhaberler.title,
  gelenhaberlerimage.id AS Expr4,
  gelenhaberlerimage.HaberKodu AS Expr5,
  gelenhaberlerimage.BuyukResim
FROM
  gelenhaberaciklama 
INNER JOIN
  gelenhaberler ON gelenhaberaciklama.HaberKodu = gelenhaberler.HaberKodu 
INNER JOIN
  gelenhaberlerimage ON gelenhaberaciklama.HaberKodu = gelenhaberlerimage.HaberKodu 
GROUP BY
  gelenhaberaciklama.id,
  gelenhaberaciklama.HaberKodu,
  gelenhaberler.id,
  gelenhaberler.HaberKodu,
  gelenhaberler.Sehir,
  gelenhaberler.title,
  gelenhaberlerimage.id,
  gelenhaberlerimage.HaberKodu,
  gelenhaberlerimage.BuyukResim 
HAVING
  (COUNT(gelenhaberlerimage.HaberKodu) > 1)
```

Comment: could you perhaps reframe the question with a simplified example? obviously we dn't know which of your tables / columns here are the duplicated ones; a fake example with 2 tables each with max 3 columns and some dummy data - plus your intended results - would make it **much** clearer what you're asking

Comment: You can try to use DISTINCT, like this "SELECT DISTINCT ..."

Comment: Just as a fun fact: you can actually use a UNION to deduplicate data. So SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC FROM TableA UNION SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC FROM TableA results in distinct values.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT not inner join?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Distinct` with `Select` statement to avoid repeating records. Here is a link which might help [SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: I think this is probably more of a comment than it is an actual answer.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT not inner join?

Comment: Distinct along with inner join. Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567288/sql-server-inner-join-with-distinct)