# Select data from other tables by foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

Users:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Carol |

Colors:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Red |
| 102 | Black |
| 103 | Blue |
| 104 | Yellow |

Votes

| id | user | vote_01 | vote_02 | vote_03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 103 | 101 | 104 |

I would like to see this result

| id | name | vote_01 | vote_02 | vote_03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Carol | Blue | Red | Yellow |

Now I have 3 row in the result set, but I want only 1. (vote_01, _02, _03 have hiearchy, i want to store them in one row / user )

```sql
SELECT votes.id, users.name AS username, colors.name 
FROM votes 
JOIN users ON votes.user=users.id 
JOIN colors ON (votes.vote_01=colors.id OR votes.vote_02=colors.id OR votes.vote_03=colors.id)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567288/sql-server-inner-join-with-distinct i think this would help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Votes colors are independent, so each separate vote index must be converted to according color with separate independent colors table's copy:

```sql
SELECT votes.id, 
       users.name AS username, 
       c1.name vote_01, 
       c2.name vote_02, 
       c3.name vote_03
FROM votes 
JOIN users ON votes.user=users.id 
JOIN colors с1 ON votes.vote_01=c1.id
JOIN colors с2 ON votes.vote_02=c2.id
JOIN colors с3 ON votes.vote_03=c3.id
```

Comment: Thank you. :) I tried to paste your code and it didn't work (php file and phpmyadmin). Then I typed it into my earlier sql string the code and everthing was ok. I compared the strings and your "c" chars after "JOIN colors" are different from my local "c". :) I have to rewrite that 3 "c" letter.